# Dependency injection for repository pattern in WCF service using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, dependency-injection, repository

I have WCF service that takes in IRepository.

```
IRepository repository;

public MyWcfService(IRepository repository)
{
    this.repository= repository;
}
```

The repository is need to be based on Entity Framework. It has methods `Get`, `Save`, etc...

My question is how should I implement this repository class, if I want to create and dispose `DbContext` every time when I called method from this WCF service class.

P.S. I'm using Ninject library for resolving dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take your database context as a dependency to your repository class then your repository class should implement **IDisposable** and in **Dispose** method you should be disposing the database context.

Your repository should be disposed at the end of http request processing therefor you should register **IRepository** using InRequestScope(). You should also register your WCF Service using InRequestScope() so it does not outlive the IRepository.

Here's documentation on **InRequestScope()**:
https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope

and difference between object scopes in ninject:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

Using dependency injection in WCF is a bit different.  You need to hook into the Instance creation pipeline, and service host.

There's a specific Ninject extension to make this easier: Ninject.extensions.Wcf

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf

There's also this blog that will explain how to use it:

http://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/10/24/using-ninject-with-wcf-services/

Note: this is a bit involved, so sorry for the link-only references... someone else is free to create a full answer based on this.